# Scroll to bottom in Ionic Vue

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic5, ionic-vue

I develop a chat app in Ionic Vue. To always see the latest messages, I have to scoll to the bottom automatically.

For web I use vue-chat-scroll, but this does not work with Ionic Vue.

I have tried a lot of different tactics but nothing works:

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("your_div");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

or

```
this.scrollIntoView(false);
```

or

```
var element = document.getElementById("scroll");
element.scrollIntoView();
```

or

```
vue-scroll-to with a hidden anchor at the end of the view
```

I have also tried different methods of listing the chat messages:

- a combination of IonGrid with Rows
- a normal ul / li list
- just with divs

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "ion-content" component, https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content

It has many methods and events for scrolling.

Comment: Thank you very much, but that's what i came up with too - and it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call the method `.scrollToBottom()` on the `<ion-content>` element.
You can use the following approach, refering the `ion-content` with a ref and calling the method scrollToBottom bellow:

```
<template>
<ion-content ref="content">

</ion-content>
</template>

export default defineComponent({
  methods: {
    scrollToBottom(){
      this.$refs['content'].scrollToBottom()
    }
  },
});
</script>
```